# Programatically changing template of a page

Tags: page-template

Is there a way to change the **Template** of a **page** from **Default Template** to another programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the wp_postmeta table, you can see the page template is stored there.

Therefore, a simple call to `update_post_meta` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)) should do the trick :

```
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'my_template.php' );
```

The filename and extension is necessary, as per my example.